# Karma: ReferenceError: app is not defined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I followed the tutorial from http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html for testing AngularJS apps with Karma.

My karma.conf.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
      'public/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',
      'public/bower_components/d3/d3.js',
      'public/bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.js',
      'public/bower_components/angularjs-nvd3-directives/dist/angularjs-nvd3-directives.js',
      'public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'public/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/*Spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And my test:

```
describe("app", function() {

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  it('should have a HomeController', function() {
    expect(app.HomeController).not.to.equal(null);
  });

});
```

public/scripts/app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'app.controllers',
  'nvd3ChartDirectives'
]);
```

I get an output in the console saying: app should have a HomeController FAILED
    ReferenceError: app is not defined

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your module `app` is defined inside `app.js`. Can you show use the code? Maybe you want to change `'public/scripts/*.js',` to `'public/scripts/**/*.js',` so every subdirectory gets included in you tests

Comment: Updated question, but getting the same output.

Comment: Your base path has to point where your scripts for application are. Ours is in /app, so base path is defined and ../app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
describe('app', function(){
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var ctrl, scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('HomeController', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should have defined HomeController', function() {
    expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
  });
}
```